# R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration conflicts with AbstractR2dbcConfiguration on bean 'r2dbcDatabaseClient' bean creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

Need help

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages = "com.paymentservice.repository", databaseClientRef = "databaseClient")
public class PaymentR2dbcConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Value("${payment.data.mssql.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${payment.data.mssql.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${payment.data.mssql.database}")
    private String database;

    @Value("${payment.data.mssql.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${payment.data.mssql.password}")
    private String password;

    /**
     * An implementation of {@link ConnectionFactory} for creating connections to
     * a Microsoft SQL Server database using R2DBC.
     *
     * @return A factory for creating {@link Connection}s.
     */
    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new MssqlConnectionFactory(
            MssqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host(host)
                .port(port)
                .database(database)
                .username(username)
                .password(password).build());
    }
}
```

I m getting

> quote The bean 'r2dbcDatabaseClient', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/r2dbc/R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/paymentservice/configurations/PaymentR2dbcConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

I m using

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mssql</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hey @Shantanu , please check the answer. I hope it helps solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Boot starter to configure R2dbc automatically.And you want to customize the R2dbc configuration via `AbstractR2dbcConfiguration`.

1. If you are using more than one connection in your application, and use this config to add another connection factory, try to add a `name` attribute to `@Bean` to identify multiple beans.

   ```java
    @Bean(name="myConn")
    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {}
   ```
2. If you want to override the default `ConnectionFactory` created by Spring Boot starter, add an extra `@Primary` on it.

   ```java
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {}
   ```

Comment: Is it mandatory to set ConnectionFactory? I was not creating ConnectionFactory Bean when using 0.8.7 version of r2dbc-postgres. But it needs to be created in 0.9.1 version or else it throws expection.

Comment: @ShivangMIttal yes, but you can autowire `ConnectionFactory` and return so the default one.

Answer (score 0):

**You have missed to annotate the method `connectionFactory` with `Bean`**.
Check the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#r2dbc.connectionfactory)

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new MssqlConnectionFactory(
            MssqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host(host)
                .port(port)
                .database(database)
                .username(username)
                .password(password).build());
    }
```

If the problem still persists in case you have any overriding bean defined in any of your configuration class, then you should use this property:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Starting in Spring 5.1, the `BeanDefinitionOverrideException` was introduced to allow developers to automatically throw the exception to prevent any unexpected bean overriding.

Comment: above solution doesn't work for me. Spring boot has now included R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration, whereas AbstractR2dbcConfiguration in spring-data-r2dbc having a conflict on beans.

Answer (score -1):

this is an open issue in Spring-boot and spring-data-r2dbc see post:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/296

and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21586

The solution which works for me is to use default **R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration** and remove the custom configuration **AbstractR2dbcConfiguration** until Spring team fixed it.

Below properties are used to initialize the **R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration**

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:mssql://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6515/*****
    username: xxxx_xxxx
    password: xxxxx
```

---

The second solution which works for me is to exclude **R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration** using below code.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration.class,
 R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Comment: No @Shantanu it works. I have a working solution here. https://github.com/abhi2495/multitenant-r2dbc-poc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/persistence/config/ConnectionConfig.java

Comment: Defining the properties in app yaml isnt mandatory,bro. Please check my repo.

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty Bro .. I am surprised that your project is working. But if you I check my dependency jars and its version. 
```[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: Not sure bro. Probably you are missing something, the `Bean` annotation as I mentioned. I too had missed that at first and was getting the same exception. But it's definitely working. The Github issues you have shared are both CLOSED. If you can share your code, it will be good

Comment: spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE you can see it has r2dbc package with R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class .... I can't skip from it and had to pass spring.r2dbc properties.

Comment: Please try once the code from my repo , replacing the `RoutingConnectionFactory` with your `MssqlConnectionFactory` . And why do you need this `@EnableR2dbcRepositories` ? You can use `@Repository` annotations on your repo interfaces. Spring boot will automatically do component sccan